# Nullable column as foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I have customers table in the database. A customer is associated with an industry. Because of the requirement, `industry_id` is null when customer is created. later it will be updated and correct industry id is added.

Now, when I want to add this column as foreign key it shows following error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `customers` add constraint `customers_industry_id_foreign` foreign key (`industry_id`) references `industries`
>      (`id`))

I have following code in customers migration.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->comment="Customer Identifier";
            $table->bigInteger('customer_category_id')->unsigned()->comment="Customer Category Identifier";
            $table->bigInteger('industry_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->comment="Industry Identifier";
            $table->string('email')->unique()->comment="Customer Email";
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('industry_id')->references('id')->on('industries');
            $table->foreign('customer_category_id')->references('id')->on('customer_categories');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
    }
}
```

Here is industries migration.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateIndustriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('industries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->comment="Industry Indetifier";
            $table->string('name')->comment="Industry Name";
            $table->boolean('status')->default(true)->comment="Active or Inactive";
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('industries');
    }
}
```

Is it impossible to achieve what I want ? or it is just illogical ? 
If I am able to add foreign key then I can take various advantages of using foreign key.

Comment: change your id(primary_key) in industry table to unique key and then try.

Comment: Can you show the migration for `industries`?

Comment: @Jerodev okay sure

Comment: I have added industries migration. Is there anything wrong ? suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the `unsigned` from the `industry_id` so that the types of the columns are the same

Comment: @Teun In the customers migration ?

Comment: @SagarGautam yes

Comment: @Teun Still same issue.

Comment: Have you checked that the `industries` table exists at the point in time when the `customers` table is created?

Comment: @Teun Let me check

Comment: @Teun Yes, Industries created before customer.

Answer (score 0):

change your id(primary_key) in industry table to unique key and then try

Comment: I've added in question

Comment: please goto your database and check the table structure, mostly the id of industry table is primary key auto generated. please add your industry table structure from database also.